# Can we use left join instead of right join by placing orders of tables?

Tags: mysql, database

We all are much familiar with left join & right joins. Can someone give one example where desired result can be found by only left join not by right join (Because we can change position of tables )? Actually I was asked this question in an interview.

Comment: If you are familiar with left and right joins, why do you ask this question?

Comment: Suppose you are using 'A left join B', & assume there are no 'right join' type of thing, then right join operation can be done by changing order of tables, i.e. B left join A. [First writing B & then A]. Got it now?

Comment: Right join is just a left join with the tables the other way round.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, we can.

> Right and left outer joins are functionally equivalent. Neither provides any functionality that the other does not, so right and left outer joins may replace each other as long as the table order is switched.

You can find the complete explanation in the [*Right outer join* section of the *Join* article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Right_outer_join).

Also, there is a helpful description about joins on the [CodingHorror blog](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/), where you can see the difference visually.